# Rolling time-based groupby() mean for non-index datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to find out if a player has won more than half of their previous games (not including the current game) in the last 4.5 hours. Variations of `...rolling('4.5h')...` do not work, as the time column is not an index, and cannot be turned into one with `set_index('game_t')`.

Games are indicated by the `gid` (game ID) column, and 'w' and 'l' indicate wins and losses, respectively, in the `wl` column. Game times for each game id are stored in `game_t`

I have a DataFrame for which the following is a good minimal approximation:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'game_t': [pd.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(hours=n) for n in range(10)],
                    'player': [*'abacabaccb'],
                    'wl': ['w','l']*5,
                    'gid': [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]})
df.game_t = df.groupby('gid').game_t.transform('first')
df
#                       game_t player wl  gid
# 0 2019-07-05 15:00:23.840588      a  w    1
# 1 2019-07-05 15:00:23.840588      b  l    1
# 2 2019-07-05 13:00:23.840605      a  w    2
# 3 2019-07-05 13:00:23.840605      c  l    2
# 4 2019-07-05 11:00:23.840611      a  w    3
# 5 2019-07-05 11:00:23.840611      b  l    3
# 6 2019-07-05 09:00:23.840618      a  w    4
# 7 2019-07-05 09:00:23.840618      c  l    4
# 8 2019-07-05 07:00:23.840623      c  w    5
# 9 2019-07-05 07:00:23.840623      b  l    5
```

IOW, given the above, I need a column, call it 'bta' for "better than average," like so:

```
#                           gt player wl  gid   bta
# 0 2019-07-05 15:00:23.840588      a  w    1  True
# 1 2019-07-05 15:00:23.840588      b  l    1 False
# 2 2019-07-05 13:00:23.840605      a  w    2  True
# 3 2019-07-05 13:00:23.840605      c  l    2 False
# 4 2019-07-05 11:00:23.840611      a  w    3  True
# 5 2019-07-05 11:00:23.840611      b  l    3 False
# 6 2019-07-05 09:00:23.840618      a  w    4 False
# 7 2019-07-05 09:00:23.840618      c  l    4  True
# 8 2019-07-05 07:00:23.840623      c  w    5 False
# 9 2019-07-05 07:00:23.840623      b  l    5 False
```

No matter where I try `set_index('game_t')`, pandas insists that the index must be monotonic. I understand that the `game_t` column is not monotonic in the "always increasing" or "always decreasing" sense because it has duplicates, grouped indices should be monotonic, in that no player plays at a given time more than once.*

For example, the following:

```py
df['bta'] = df.groupby('player').apply(lambda g: g.set_index('game_t').wl.eq('w').rolling('4.5h', min_periods=0).mean())
```

Results in:

> Traceback (most recent call last):....pandas internals stacktrace joy...
>   ...ValueError: index must be monotonic

At any rate, none of my previous attempts have any value, as they all either give the wrong answer or trigger variations on the typical "You can't get there from here, and you were kind of stupid for even trying (Have you tried using `apply`, in spite of the fact that you might have meant `transform`?)" pandas error messages.

* Aside: The pandas developers do not know what "monotonic" means, because it actually means "constant, or nondecreasing, or nonincreasing;" monotonicity implies neither "increasing" nor "decreasing." They seem to mean "strictly increasing or strictly decreasing."

Comment: @ALollz Can you answer the question I posed?

Comment: Why exactly # 6 has `bta` equal `False`? Is it because it's the first `a`'s game?

Comment: I'm not a huge expert on rolling, and the complication of not counting the concurrent row complicates things. I can say, the issue is that your Index is `monotonic_decreasing`, not `monotonic`. I.e. see the output of `df2.groupby('player').apply(lambda g: g.set_index('game_t').index.is_monotonic_decreasing)` and `df2.groupby('player').apply(lambda g: g.set_index('game_t').index.is_monotonic)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang, yes, and I'm looking at past games only. "Have you been better than average up to the start of the current game?," essentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any of your issues to be a problem:

1. `game_t` is not index: set it as index
2. `game_t` is not monotonic: sort it

Here's my solution

```
# sort values and set index
df = df.sort_values('game_t').set_index('game_t')

# if the player wins -> for rolling
df['is_win'] = df.wl.eq('w')

# closed='left' option skip the current game
win_mean = (df.groupby('player')
              .is_win.rolling('4.5H', closed='left')
              .mean().reset_index()
           )

df = df.reset_index().merge(win_mean, on = ['game_t', 'player'])
df['bta'] = df.is_win_y.gt(0.5)

df.sort_values(['gid', 'wl'], ascending=[True, False])
```

gives:

```
                      game_t player wl  gid  is_win_x  is_win_y    bta
8 2019-07-05 15:00:23.840588      a  w    1      True       1.0   True
9 2019-07-05 15:00:23.840588      b  l    1     False       0.0  False
6 2019-07-05 13:00:23.840605      a  w    2      True       1.0   True
7 2019-07-05 13:00:23.840605      c  l    2     False       0.0  False
4 2019-07-05 11:00:23.840611      a  w    3      True       1.0   True
5 2019-07-05 11:00:23.840611      b  l    3     False       0.0  False
2 2019-07-05 09:00:23.840618      a  w    4      True       NaN  False
3 2019-07-05 09:00:23.840618      c  l    4     False       1.0   True
0 2019-07-05 07:00:23.840623      c  w    5      True       NaN  False
1 2019-07-05 07:00:23.840623      b  l    5     False       NaN  False
```

You can drop the two columns `is_win` if wished.